# Replace specific string with blank even if partial match with another column value

Tags: sql-server, string-manipulation

I have a scenario to replace entire string from a set of comma delimited strings, if partial word matches with another column.

I found very complex to explain in words and hence I have explained through a screenshot having various examples.

Please help me with stored procedure or a function or query to get results as in **Required_result** column as in below screen shot.

[image: screenshot]

I tried `STRING_SPLIT` function to split values and join the tables. I am struck with the logic to solve this problem.

Comment: So you want to remove any words in `Col2` that exist in `Col1`? Does the order of the remaining words in `Col2` need to be preserved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    ID integer NOT NULL,
    Col1 varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
    Col2 varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
    Required_result varchar(8000) NULL
);

INSERT dbo.Test
    (ID, Col1, Col2)
VALUES
    (1, 'pencil red', 'charcoal, pencil, scale'),
    (2, 'pencil red', 'charcoal, red, scale'),
    (3, 'ball pen', 'eraser, pen'),
    (4, 'ball pen', 'ball, box'),
    (5, 'ball pen', 'eraser, ball pen'),
    (6, 'ball pen', 'eraser, pen ball'),
    (7, 'ball pen', 'eraser, watercan, bag'),
    (8, 'Note book', 'Note book'),
    (9, 'Note book', 'Note book, eraser'),
    (10, 'Note book', '');
```

#### Solution

```
UPDATE dbo.Test
SET Required_result =
    ISNULL
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                -- Reassemble parts with no matches
                result = STRING_AGG(LTRIM(SS.[value]), ', ')
            FROM dbo.Test AS T2
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT
            (
                -- Remove commas before splitting
                REPLACE(T2.Col2, ',', ''),
                -- Split on spaces
                SPACE(1)
            ) AS SS
            WHERE
                -- For the current outer ID
                T2.ID = dbo.Test.ID
                -- Current part has no match
                AND 0 = 
                    CHARINDEX
                    (
                        SPACE(1) + LTRIM(SS.[value]) + SPACE(1), 
                        SPACE(1) + T2.Col1 + SPACE(1)
                    )
        ),
        -- Empty string instead of NULL if everything matched
        SPACE(0)
    );
```

#### Result

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Required_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pencil red | charcoal, pencil, scale | charcoal, scale |
| 2 | pencil red | charcoal, red, scale | charcoal, scale |
| 3 | ball pen | eraser, pen | eraser |
| 4 | ball pen | ball, box | box |
| 5 | ball pen | eraser, ball pen | eraser |
| 6 | ball pen | eraser, pen ball | eraser |
| 7 | ball pen | eraser, watercan, bag | eraser, watercan, bag |
| 8 | Note book | Note book |  |
| 9 | Note book | Note book, eraser | eraser |
| 10 | Note book |  |  |

[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/8OR8mHrU)

---

If you need to *guarantee* the ordering of Col2 string components is preserved, pass a value of 1 in the optional *enable_ordinal* parameter of `STRING_SPLIT` (Azure SQL Database or SQL Server 2022 required) and add `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.ordinal)` to the `STRING_AGG` aggregate:

```
UPDATE dbo.Test
SET Required_result =
    ISNULL
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                -- Reassemble parts with no matches
                result = STRING_AGG(LTRIM(SS.[value]), ', ')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.ordinal)
            FROM dbo.Test AS T2
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT
            (
                -- Remove commas before splitting
                REPLACE(T2.Col2, ',', ''),
                -- Split on spaces
                SPACE(1),
                -- Enable ordinal
                1
            ) AS SS
            WHERE
                -- For the current outer ID
                T2.ID = dbo.Test.ID
                -- Current part has no match
                AND 0 = 
                    CHARINDEX
                    (
                        SPACE(1) + LTRIM(SS.[value]) + SPACE(1), 
                        SPACE(1) + T2.Col1 + SPACE(1)
                    )
        ),
        -- Empty string instead of NULL if everything matched
        SPACE(0)
    );
```